# How to make one pdf from many pdfs where their filename are also shown as label in the one pdf?

Tags: pdfpages

I have a directory named `Titlepage` where the files(minimum 10 pdf) are `titlepage_1.pdf`, `titlepage_2.pdf`, `titlepage_3.pdf`... . Each has one page.

This directory also hosted in Github so that people can download the title pages easily. The Github directory contains corresponding LaTeX file also.

I want to make a combined pdf using these where each page contains 4 pdfs(`pdfnup --nup 2x2 ....`). And labeling each title page with their original name. So that anybody can choose a pdf by comparing all in one pdf and then download what title page he needs.

I guess it can be done using `LaTeX` since it has `pdfpages` package.

[image]

or

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you have so far? Please include a minimal working example that compiles as a base for others to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for `pdfpages`, this can be done with `graphicx`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{expl3,graphicx,url}
\newcommand\addpage[1]{%
  \parbox{\dimexpr.5\linewidth}{%
      \centering%
      \fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{#1}}\\%
      \path{#1}%
  }%
  \penalty0\relax
}
\lineskip=0pt plus 1fil
\begin{document}
\noindent
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_step_inline:nnnn{1}{1}{100}{
  \file_if_exist:nT{pg_#1.pdf}{
    \addpage{pg_#1.pdf}
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

[image]

If there might be more that 100 files, the 100 has to be increased.

Comment: It may be better if you use loop for adding the pdf. So, when there are more pdf in that directory they can be added just recompiling the code.

Comment: I added a loop which works for up to 100 files, but looping over all files in a directory would only be possible in LuaTeX or with shell-escapes.

Comment: Will your solution work for any named pdf file in that directory? Suppose `pdffile_1.pdf`, `pdffile_2.pdf`, `pg_3.pdf`. I have `titlepage_1.pdf`, `titlepage_2.pdf`, `...` so your solution not works.

Comment: It works when I put `titlepage` instead of `pg`.

Comment: You can also provide an alternative solution that works for all pdf in that directory.